# How to hide button is Sencha Touch 2.1

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I've found similar questions on this site but none of the answers has been working for me. This is button I want to hide (view):

```
{
        xtype: 'button',
        id: 'btn_messenger',
        text: 'Messenger'
    }
```

Controller for that view has init function:

```
init : function() {
    var me = this;
    me.callParent();
    me.hideMessengerButton(me);
}
```

This is the function that should hide button:

```
hideMessengerButton: function(me) {
    var user = me.getLoggedUser(); // return user or undefined
    if (user == undefined) {
        Ext.select('#btn_messenger').hide(); // Does nothing
    }
}
```

I've tried these options:

`Ext.getCmp('btn_messenger').hide(); // Ext.getCmp('btn_messenger') returns undefined`

`Ext.getCmp('#btn_messenger').hide(); // Ext.getCmp('#btn_messenger') returns undefined`

In controller's refs there is `btn_messenger: '#btn_messenger'`, so I've tried:

`this.getBtn_messenger().hide() // this.getBtn_messenger() returns undefined`

Thanks for help in advance.

PS.: I don't know if this matters but the view mentioned above is not the main view. It is pushed after button tap on the main view.

**EDIT:**

Here is the controller:

```
Ext.define('First.controller.HomePage', {
extend : 'First.controller.Controller',
requires : ['First.view.Main', 'First.view.HomePage'],

config : {
    refs : {
        pnl_home: 'pnl_home',
        btn_messenger : '#btn_messenger'
    },

    control : {
        btn_messenger : {
            tap : 'btn_openMessenger'
        }
        pnl_home: {
            show: 'hideMessengerButton'
        }
    },
},

init : function() {
    var me = this;
    me.callParent();
},


btn_openMessenger : function() {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Open', 'Messenger');
},

/**
 * Hide meseenger button when user's not logged in
 */
hideMessengerButton : function() {
    var me = this;
    var user = me.getLoggedUser();
    if (user == undefined) {
        me.getBtn_messenger().setHidden(true);
    }
}
```

});

Comment: why call a seperate function? just put Ext.getCmp('btn_messenger').hide(); in your init function

Comment: do you have var btn_messenger = new Ext.Button({  }); around your declaration of the button? if you don't that may be the reason of the undefined

Comment: It's separate because logged user is being checked. I've declared btn_messenger in controller's refs. I believe it's enough http://localhost/sencha-touch-2.1.0-gpl/docs/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller

Comment: The issue is why `Ext.getCmp('btn_messenger')` returns undefined. Isn't that button visible? Is your hiding code executing before view is rendered fully? You can use debugger to find answers

Comment: It should be visible, because I'm able to tap it. Ive added Controller code. `btn_openMessenger` function is triggered after taping the `btn_messenger`

Comment: Well, I've found out, that `hideMessengerButton` is called right after Application launch. I need something like `onPush` or `afterPush` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added `pnl_home: 'pnl_home'`, to refs and called show event on the panel. Modified code can be found above, in my initial post.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Button-method-setHidden

in your action 
replaces refs

```
refs : {
        btnMessenger: '#btn_messenger'
    },
```

then when you need this button on action use next

```
this.getBtnMessenger().setHidden(true)
```

also on init button are not yet added to dom as i remember

```
lauch : function() {
    this.hideMessengerButton();
},
hideMessengerButton: function() {
    var user = this.getLoggedUser(); // return user or undefined
    if (user == undefined) {
        this.getBtnMessenger().setHidden(true); // Does nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `setHidden` function. But I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setHidden' of undefined

Comment: Got it. you have defined btn_messenger as an id, i am not sure how it can be handled by sencha but try getBtnMessenger() or rename your  id: 'btn_messenger', to  id: 'btnMessenger', then getBtnMessenger will work for sure.

Comment: Sencha can handle underscore in ID (I use this kind of naming in other controllers). The problem is that `this.getBtnMessenger()` returns `undefined` as @ThinkFloyd mentioned (comments to my question).

Comment: then do hide button on launch event, sorry i did not saw that you are running oninit

Comment: I've tried that already but it's launched right after the Application launch...There are events `show` and `painted`. `show` is the one I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for help...Look at my Controller code above. It's working with the `show` event.